# Which dataset should I use?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

The title may have been a bit vague, but I will appreciate some ideas for the current problem I have.

Here is a dataset:

```
1   1/1/2013
2   1/1/2013
3   1/1/2013
1   1/2/2013
2   1/2/2013
1   1/3/2013
2   1/3/2013
3   1/3/2013
```

So, I begin with the first record, and see if there is another 1 in my list. If there is, I ignore it, and go back to the second record. If there is another 2 in my list, I ignore it, and go back to the 3rd record, and so on and so forth.

Now, the desired result of this list, that I am looking for is <1, 1/3/2013>, since no other record of 1 exists below it.

Similarly, in this dataset:

```
1   1/1/2013
2   1/1/2013
3   1/1/2013
1   1/2/2013
2   1/2/2013
3   1/2/2013
4   1/2/2013
1   1/3/2013
2   1/3/2013
3   1/3/2013
```

The desired result would be <4, 1/2/2013>, since there is no other occurrence of 4 down the list.

My question is, how would I go about doing this, what standard STL container can I use? Further more, these are the results returned by a query.

I am sorry I don't use boost or any of the other libraries, and looking to get this done with std variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two maps - one map to store mapping from the key (your first column) to the value (your second column) and second map to store mapping from the key (your first column) to the record number:

```
std::map<int, std::string> m1;
std::map<int, int> m2;

int counter = 0;
while (...)
{
  <...get record...>
  m1[record.key] = record.value;
  m2[record.key] = counter++;
}
```

Then you need to scan the second map **m2** in order to find the key with minimal position:

```
int keyMin = <...big number...>, posMin = <...big number...>;
for (std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = m2.begin(); it != m2.end(); ++it)
{
  if (it->second < posMin)
  {
    keyMin = it->first;
    posMin = it->second;
  }
}
```

The result will be the first key, for which there are no records with this key down the road. Using this key and the first map **m1** you'll be able to find its corresponding value.

Comment: So, what would I do, if an element already exists? When I insert <1,1/2/2013>, what will happen to m[1] ?

Comment: If you insert a new "value" for the same "key" then the old "value" will be lost - this is what you want, right? Maps consist of pairs (key, value), and the key is unique.

Comment: So - insert all your data in the map, then for each "key" (your first column) you'll get the **latest** "value" (your second column).

Comment: I don't want the latest value. Please look at my example, it is the value which doesn't occur again down the list.

Comment: Your description of what you want is a little bit vague. For example, in your first dataset you could select <2, 1/3/2013> because (as you wrote) "no other record of 2 exists below it". May be, you are looking for the **first** record with this condition?

Comment: No, I want to break out of the loop once I find that no other record of 1 exists below it.

Comment: Your "break from the loop" means exactly the same as my "first record with this condition". Anyway you must finish the loop because any ongoing record can break your search condition. You need to scan all your records and gather info in some data structure, then extract an answer from this data structure. I'll update my answer - thank you for clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can check from the bottom, and remember the first(last when counting from the top) appearance of each index. And after You've done this (in time O(n)) You can take the last You found.

Answer (score 0):

What does query return? You can choose `std::vector<some-structure>` if it returns a known structure, or `std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >` if it returns a string list.
Then going from bottom and remembering all unique ids that you see you are able to get the last good value in o(n) time and o(n) memory.